# How much does Igss vary with temperature?

Tags: nmos, micropower

I was looking at a transistor ([BUK98190-100A/CUX](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BUK98180-100A.pdf)). I see that Igss is 100nA at 25C. How does Igss vary with temperature? Is there some way to guesstimate the max at 100C, given that the max at 25C is 100nA? I will be biasing the gate with a high value resistor. Just trying to get a grip on how much leakage I should allow for.

Comment: Generally leakage increases with temp.    I don't know the answer to your question, but I thought to make just one comment in case you're unaware.   That 25C spec is for the JUNCTION, not AMBIENT AIR TEMP.   The junction (i.e. the silicon die itself) will always be hotter than ambient.  To know what the junction temp is, you have to calculate it based on the power you intend to drop with the transistor.

Comment: It's simple calculation, alot like a series-resistor calc.  The thermal impedance of the junction-to-ambient is given in the datasheet.   I say this because if you are planning 100C ambient, your junction temp will probably vastly exceed the max rating of the part.

Comment: @KyleB *The junction (i.e. the silicon die itself) will always be hotter than ambient.* I disagree! You're correct if the MOSFET itself (the junction) is **dissipating power**. If the MOSFET  is **off** and not dissipating any power then the junction and ambient temperature will (eventually) be the same (assuming no other devices are generating heat).

Comment: The **gate leakage** \$I_{GSS}\$ is very likely mainly the result of the **ESD protection diodes** inside the MOSFET (they're needed to protect the gate oxide which is extremely fragile). So my guess is that \$I_{GSS}\$ will have a very similar temperature behavior as any ordinary silicon diode. I would use a multimeter on diode mode and test between Gate and Source, is there a diode present? Hmm, the max. rating for \$V_{GS}\$ is +/- 10 V so there's no single diode there.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie quite a few MOSFET's have built-in back-to-back Zener diodes. I thought this one didn't, though, because I thought 100nA was pretty low for Zener leakage. Spehro's answer is making me think twice.

Comment: @KyleB I know how to do the thermal calculations, but thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To a first approximation, MOSFET gates don't leak at all, it's in the sub-pA range for small-ish MOSFETs at room temperature.

The "typical" spec of 2nA is a relatively heavy current and, if correct, indicates something else may be going on, like an internal gate protection network. That could double every 10°C.

If you have one on hand you may wish to make a quick measurement to see if there really is that much leakage at 25°C.

Comment: Interesting. For some reason I thought sub uA Igss was indicative that there was no protection on the gate. I thought the protected ones were up in the uA Igss range. I don't have one on hand but I will add it to the list of stuff to check out when I build boards I guess.